# Get string from right with String.format

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, formatting

i have this string

> B0018-00000102

i need to get the last 8 chars (00000102) using only **String.format**

is possible with **substring** and split, i know it, but i need with **String.format** is possible ?

i tested with **"%.8s"**

```
String.format("%.8s", "B0018-00000102")
```

but it start from left

i need a format like **"%.8s"** but starting from the right

Comment: `String.format` is for *building* strings, not extracting/parsing them.

Comment: Have you even read the documentation of the function? As @Andreas said it is for creating output strings and not parsing them! I suggest you take a look at ``Regex`` or ``Scanner`` or ``String.substring``.

Comment: @TopSekret ::  The OP clearly states "...is possible with substring and split, i know it,..." So they are aware of other functions.

Comment: @TopSekret actually, it is for _formatting_ output. Among the many things you can configure is the maximum number of characters to print: `String.format("%.8s", string)` will give the same output as `string.substring(0, 8)`... the OP is just curious if there's a way to do this from the end of the string as opposed to the start of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading the Oracle documentation once again very carefully, and I believe their design is left-conventional, so there's no way to implement what you want by using String.format().

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: I think both the OP and you got the function wrong. See the comments under the question.

Comment: I understand clearly that String.format() is not used for parsing, but in case the OP tries to do that for educational purpose, I try to figure out a way for him. That's what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Even if `String.format` *could* do such a thing, you shouldn't.

The method is for formatting output, not extracting information. Formatting output includes the ability to format columnar output, so it makes sense to support *truncating* output, since too long values would otherwise break the format.

However, a format like `%.8s` is not intended to *substring* a value, it's simply for limiting output to prevent overflow. Although the operation is the same, the *intent* is different.

If you want to extract first 8 characters, use `substring(0, 8)`.
If you need to limit formatted output, use `%.8s`.